# Visual Studio. InstallShield. Регистрация COM компонентов при установке приложения

Tags: visual-studio, com, windowsinstaller

Разрабатывается приложение в Visual Studio 2010.
Оно состоит из 1-го решения, в котором 2 проекта: 1 COM-компонент, созданный с использованием ATL и одно Win32 EXE. Перед запуском приложения COM-компонент должен быть зарегистрирован в системе. Сейчас я регистрирую его с помощью regsrv. Но нужно сделать установщик, чтобы при запуске на других компьютерах, COM-компонент добавлялся автоматически.
Вопрос: Возможно ли сделать это при помощи Install Shield Limited? Если нет, то какие другие способы существуют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Shield Limited по умолчанию извлекает данные о COM из устанавливаемых dll при сборке msi, и регистрирует из при установке. Т.е. теоретически все должно заработать само по себе, достаточно только добавить dll или ocx в список устанавливаемых файлов.

Если этот механизм для вашего COM-объекта по какой-то причине не работает, то можно принудительно переключить его на self-registration - аналог вызова regsvr32. Это можно сделать в свойствах файла (right click по нему в списке на в разделе Files), на закладке COM & .NET Settings:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]